# curl http post request to upload a file to a website bypassing captcha [ I have key to bpass captcha]

Tags: curl, command-line, http-post

I want to upload a file to a website http://domain.com/submit.php through command line.

**I have key to bypass captcha**

I choose curl to do so.
I used wireshark to capture the post request and to analyze.

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="b.apk"\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"\r\n\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recaptcha_challenge_field"\r\n\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recaptcha_response_field"\r\n\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"\r\n\r\n
```

the page has following fields

```
1) Browse -- It is a button where I can give the path of file
2) email  --this is optional I want to ignore it.
3) recaptcha_challenge_field- a captcha image
4) recaptcha_response_field  --- I am suppose to enter the answer for captcha
5) Submit button.
```

For bypassing the captcha  I have  post parameter key value xxxxxxxxxxxx.

I tried to write curl command something like

```
curl -F "filename=/home/xxx/Desktop/a.apk&key= xxxxxxxxxxx&submit" http://domain.com/submit.php
```

Can somebody point out what am I doing wrong?

I also tried

```
curl -i -F "filename=@/home/xxx/Desktop/a.apk"  -F "key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" http://domain_name.com/submit.php
```

this also does not seem to work.